# Hibernate native sql query exception - rs cursor forward only

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-native-query

I am dealing with a legacy code that is 'not changeable' (no way to move to criteria api) and I have a little trouble with proper parameters binding. The query looks like this (`MS SQL`):

```
SELECT BRAND AS b FROM CAR WHERE (NAME LIKE :phrase OR MODEL LIKE :phrase ) AND AGE NOT IN(1997, 1998) AND (:mileage IS NULL OR MILEAGE LIKE :mileage) ORDER BY BRAND
(...)
    query.setParameter("phrase", "%" + phrase + "%");
    query.setParameter("mileage", mileage);
```

`phrase` is actually required, but because the `mileage`parameter is optional, it's done in wierd way presented above. 
The problem is that with both `phrase` and `mileage` provided, It keeps giving me following error : `java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet may only be accessed in a forward direction.`. It works wihtout `mileage` parameter provided. Why I am getting this error ?

**EDITED:**

- Running this query on db gives me no results.
- I am using `query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(type))` as well as setting `first` and `max` result on my `SQLQuery query` object.
- An error is when calling `query.list()` (used intellij `evaluate expression`)

shouldn't `query.list()` return an empty result ?

**Probable answer (in that case):**

It looks like setting `FirstResult` on the query cause that problem because - by mistake - it's a negative number.

Comment: Your SQL has `LIKE` keyword with `mileage` here `MILEAGE LIKE :mileage`, but you are not specifying `%` like you do with `phrase`. Is it done intentionally?

Comment: Yes, It is - 'cause I wanted it to be either a perfect match or not.

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing the SQL and then accessing the results?

It sounds like there are no results when executing the SQL with the `mileage` parameter and you are somehow trying to read the results anyway.

Try running the generated SQL immediately on the database and see if it returns any rows.

Comment: You are right. No rows returned when executed that query on db. The error is when I call `list()` : `query.list()`. I set debugger on that line and used intellij `Evaluate expression` and it gives me that exception. Shouldn't it return empty collection ?